# Add file with comment sharepoint client object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I use following code to add file to SharePoint library using client object model.

```
   Web web = context.Web;
                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                newFile.Url = destFileName;
                newFile.Overwrite = true;
                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                context.Load(uploadFile);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Question is, can I include my comment during this routine itself?

As it stands, I have to checkout file again and check in with comments using following code, which **makes 2 versions of file** which is unnecessary.

```
if (uploadFile.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
                    { 
                        uploadFile.CheckOut();
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }

                    uploadFile.CheckIn(checkinComments, checkinType);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to check-in file with comment in one round trip only. Here is the updated code --

```
Web web = context.Web;
                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                newFile.Url = destFileName;
                newFile.Overwrite = true;
                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                uploadFile.CheckIn("checkinComments", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Also, You do not require 'uploadFile' to load again. All pending changes will be commited by 'context.ExecuteQuery()'.

Comment: this one does not work , as on final executeQuery, error is thrown  file "filename" is not checked out.

Comment: Looks like Document Library does not have "Require Check Out" enabled. So, in this case, check if the document library has "Require Check Out" enabled before calling check-in method. If it is enabled then the file being uploaded will be checked out and it has to be check-in.